# Google Cloud SQL Postgres(Set Session_Replication_Role='Replica') || Bucardo

Tags: psql, google-cloud-sql, bucardo

I'm trying to replicate the PostgresDB from AWS to GoogleCloudSQL using Bucardo in order to avoid live transactions.

Here, Bucardo needs to set `session_replication_role='replica'` using user credentials on googlecloudsql postgres user. The postgres user on cloudsql needs superuser privileges to do this.

Is their any other way we could set role using any other users?

Comment: Any new findings on this?

Comment: Ruby rep framework supports replication without superuser privileges. I did used #ruby-rep [http://www.rubyrep.org] instead #bucardo. But both were trigger based.

Comment: Thanks for this lead. Will check it out!